# Возвращает не ожидаемое значение переменной char *?

Tags: c++, строки, функции, char, параметры

Есть переменная `char* bufer`, которую я передаю в функцию `func(bufer)`, и в этой функции ее изменяю (выделяю память,записываю информацию). Когда эта функция возвращает значение, переменная возвращается в предыдущее значение, т.е `NULL`. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: покажите нам код

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вероятно, вы делаете что-то типа

```
void func(char* buffer)
{
    ...
    buffer = ...
    ...
}
...
char * buffer;
...
func(buffer);
```

Если да - то вы передаете в функцию копию *значения, хранящегося в переменной `buffer`*, так что все, что вы делаете в функции с `buffer` - работа с копией, никак не влияющая на значение самой переменной `buffer` *вне* функции.

Если, несмотря на массу других возможностей С++, вы все равно хотите работать с массивами в стиле C, то передавайте либо указатель на переменную:

```
void func(char** buffer)
{
    ...
    *buffer = ...
    ...
}
...
char * buffer;
...
func(&buffer);
```

либо ссылку:

```
void func(char* &buffer)
{
    ...
    buffer = ...
    ...
}
...
char * buffer;
...
func(buffer);
```

Comment: …либо только изменять данные по этому указателю, а не сам указатель (в частности не выделять память итп)...

Comment: @Fat-Zer тогда уж - либо вообще не программировать :) У человека ведь достаточно точное описание, что он УЖЕ делает.

Comment: сам же понимаешь, что учитывая характер ошибки  то что человек *уже* делает может очень сильно отличаться от того, что он *хочет* сделать... а за отсутствием конкретики угадывать это, конечно, дело не благодарное, но про стандартное для Си-стиля решение — разделить выделение памяти и обработку данных, когда это возможно, упомянуть стоит...

Comment: @ Fat-Zer ,  я  думаю, если вы считаете, что нужно ответить по другому, то нужно самому написать ответ...

Comment: @Fat-Zer,  вы правы, если не учитывать один факт: автор  указал, что он в функцию передает нулевой указатель, с целью инициализации, так что данных по указателью у него нет

Answer (score 1):

лучшее решение не передавать в функцию нулевой указатель, и вместо:

```
void func(char* &buffer)
{
    ...
    buffer = ...
    ...
}
...
char * buffer;
...
func(buffer);
```

написать:

```
char* func()
{
    ...
    char* buffer = ...
    ...
    return buffer;
}
...
char * buffer = func();
```

Сами судите, зачем написать функцию с целью передавать ей нулевой указатель, чтоб его инциализировать каким то другим, если можно сразу возвратить из функции желаемый результат?..

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день. Дело в том что когда вы выделяете память внутри функции, она выделяется только в стеке внутри этой функции, как только функция заканчивается память освобождается. Для решения проблемы есть три варианта:

1 Выделять память до передачи в функцию

2 использовать буфер (переменную большого размера в которую запишется 
результат), передать его в функцию.

3 использовать string

В c# можно было бы попробовать передать значение с параметром ref, реализовано ли это в c++ не знаю

Comment: и даже последствия malloc/new[] при выходе с функции подчищаются?

Comment: Честно сказать не знаю, не пользовался. Если вам что-то известно по этому поводу, буду рад услышать ответ. Описанное выше лишь мой скудный опыт, при этом хочу заметить, что освобождалась память не всегда.
p.s. Если быть точнее, даже в случае передачи значения ссылкой, память все равно выделяется локально, поправьте если я не прав.

Comment: слишком много намешали в одном комментарии. А ответ на вопрос - это несколько глав книги.